# Play too much sound together bug

Tags: c#, audio, media-player

To play multi sound together, i found that i can use WMNLib reference, but when i try to play lots of sound togeter, like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i< 100; i++)
        {
            var S = new WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer();
            S.URL = @"E:\Music\09 - Whod Have Known.mp3";
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

program get bug and cannot play anymore. At my computer, it stop at i = 70, but can i really let the nummer much, much bigger?

Comment: Why would you want to play that many sounds?

Comment: You could mix all soundfiles into a single sample array and play this array.

Comment: actually im making a guitar simulator, and if user play it too hard, it could be about 80 sounds plays together, it can consider a bug!

Comment: @DrKoch actually i dont plan to play all them in the same time, each sound file last 1 second and i play each of them every 10 milisec, and mixing using timer is pointless when i have to play sound instantly.

Comment: "play together" and "each of them every 10 milisec" is very different. Please clearyfy your question.

Comment: But it goes the same bug problem and this playtogether thing is easier to see this bug.